# prove that if two consecutive integers are squared, that the sum always gives a remainder of 1 when divided by 4.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

prove that if two consecutive integers are squared, that the sum always gives a remainder of 1 when divided by 4.

I've set my integers to be n and n+1, squared and summed to give 2n^2+2n+1.

I'm then unclear how I show that if I divide by 4, I get a remainder of 1.

Grateful for help!

Comment: An even $n$ would always give $n^2\equiv0\pmod4$. An odd $n$ would always give $n^2\equiv1\pmod4$. Can you now use this to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Two consecutive integers are an even number and an odd number.

Let $n=2k$ and $n+1=2k+1$

$n^2 + (n+1)^2=(2k)^2 +(2k+1)^2=4k^2 + 4k^2 + 4k +1 \equiv 1 \mod 4$

Comment: This is not entirely correct, because the smaller number could be the odd one. But you can adjust to make it work in that case too.